# Undefined method `errors'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my update action of Registration controller. And I get undefined method `'errors'`. I can not use flash message here for some reason.

```
if subjects_selected.blank?
      @registration = Registration.where(:student_id => params[:registration][:student_id], :semester_id => params[:registration][:semester_id] )
      redirect_to editreg_registrations_path(@registration.first.id, params[:registration][:student_id], params[:registration][:semester_id]), @registration.errors.add(:You_have_to_register_for_at_least_one_subject) and return
    end
```

How can I access error method here?

Comment: Can you post your full error stack.?

Answer (score 1):

you can take the method in  Registration model for error displaying the errors
like

```
error_array = Registration.validate_subjects(params[:registration][:student_id],params[:registration][:semester_id])
```

then in Registration model

```
def validate_subjects(student_id, semester_id)
is_registration = self.where(:student_id=>student_id,:semester_id =>semester_id)
error_array=[]
if !is_registration
//RIGHT THE CODE 
error_array << "You_have_to_register_for_at_least_one_subjec"
end
error_array
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if subjects_selected.blank?
    @registration = Registration.where(:student_id => params[:registration][:student_id], :semester_id => params[:registration][:semester_id] )

   if !@registration.errors     
   redirect_to editreg_registrations_path(@registration.first.id, params[:registration][:student_id], params[:registration][:semester_id])
  else
  @registration.errors.add(:You_have_to_register_for_at_least_one_subject)
  end

end
```